# Alignment lables and inputs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have  two bootstrap column with labels and inputs. After two column a want to add one big input. But I can't setup alignment by labels. This is what I mean:
[image]

How to do this? 
Link to [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wiqevizima/edit?html,output)

Comment: Mathematically it's not possible with bootstrap's grid system. Not the way you're doing it. Try changing the size of fields 1-3 to be 6 cols instead of 7, or even 8. It should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width of label of fields 1-3 is `7 / 12 * 3 / 12 = 7 / 48`. You can't get to that number with multiples of 12. You need to change your layout to make it work. I suggest changing the 7 to either 6 or 8. It should be possible to do what you want then.

Answer (score 1):

In the bootstrap grid system, the class 'col-sm-2' will take 16.6%, which is changing the layout, So take  <div class="col-sm-8"> and <div class="col-sm-4"> and it will work for you, check the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <form method="get" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Field 1</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input class="form-control" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Field 2</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input class="form-control" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Field 3</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input class="form-control"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Field 4</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <p class="input-group reset">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"/>            
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Field 4</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <p class="input-group reset">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"/>            
            </p>
          </div>
        </div><div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Field 4</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <p class="input-group reset">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"/>            
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
       
       
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" 
              placeholder="some big text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-details" ng-click="saveChanges()"
          type="submit">Save changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```